# Как проверять успешно ли опубликован пост на разных CMS

Tags: php, post, curl, responsive

Пишу постилку на сайты и форумы: DLE, phpBB, vBulletin, SMF. Использую curl php. Пытаюсь добавить проверку статуса выполнения публикации. На данный момент пробую просто код ответа сервера, но очень часто, даже при ошибке публикации код все равно 200. Есть ли способы какие-то надежнее?

Comment: Не надо писать спамилку :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов почему?

Comment: Потому что спам - это плохо и его не любят.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вы же не спрашивали у меня что я буду публиковать на сайты. Почему вы решили что это будет спам который не любят?

Comment: Владельцы сайтов вам явно не давали разрешения, иначе такой задачи бы не стояло. А раз разрешения на массовую рассылку вам не давали - это спам, независимо от вашего мнения и того, что именно вы будете публиковать. Просто по определению, с которым рекомендую ознакомиться, как и с УК.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Владельцы сайтов, разрешения как раз таки давали, некоторые сайты лично мои. С чего вы вообще решили что это спам?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в общем случае сообщество однажды решило, что мы не будем закрывать вопросы из-за возможности того, что ответы на них могут быть использованы в целях спама или ещё чём-то нехорошем. Общая мысль была такова, что такие вопросы могут быть полезны людям, занимающимся ИБ, например.